# Modify Django QuerySet object after it has been created

Tags: python, django

Let's say I make the following query:

```
showtimes = ShowTime.objects.filter(
    start_date__lte=start,
    end_date__gte=end,
    movie__slug=movie.slug,
    city=city,
    visible=1)
```

Now I want to have a function that takes in that `queryset object` and filters the results further based on some other attributes, something like this:

```
def is_subtitled_3d(showtimes):
    return (
        showtimes.language == LANGUAGE_SUBTITLED and
        showtimes.type_vip == None and
        showtimes.type_3d == 1 and
        showtimes.type_gtmax == None and
        showtimes.type_xd == None)
```

Would something like that work for modifying the object or is there a different way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

querysets are [lazy and chainable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy)

you can filter `showtimes` as many times as you like.  I don't believe your syntax is correct but you can use the standard `filter` to keep filter a queryset

```
def is_subtitled_3d(showtimes):
  return showtimes.filter(
    language=LANGUAGE_SUBTITLED,        
    type_vip__isnull=True,
    type_3d=1,
    type_gtmax__isnull=True,
    type_xd__isnull=True
  )
```

maybe if a user wants to filter on 3d movies, to illustrate how you can combine filters, something like:

```
showtimes = ShowTime.objects.filter(
    start_date__lte=start,
    end_date__gte=end,
    movie__slug=movie.slug,
    city=city,
    visible=1)

if request.GET.get('is_3d_movie'):
  showtimes = showtimes.filter(type_3d=1)
etc...
```

Comment: This is great, exactly what I needed, thanks for including the documentation link.

Comment: By the way, is using  `is__null` a better practice than using `==None`?

Comment: @edu222 hmm i don't know what exactly `=None` does, but `isnull` will translate to your query to `IS NULL`.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull

Comment: gotcha thanks, from what I understand it does the same thing.

Comment: Not really, as your "version" wont work. X==None is a python code for comparing x wih None (known as null/nil) . Django query builder does not parse python code, instead it uses named (keyword) arguments with special meaning of double underscore.